# Finding the Multiplicative Inverse of a Field

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F$ be a field such that $p:=x^2 + x+1 \neq 0$ for all $x \in F$. Let $G = F \times F$, with elements written $(a,b) = a+jb$, $a,b \in F$, for a formal symbol $j$. Addition is defined componentwise and multiplication is defined as follows:

$$(a +bj)(c+dj)=(ac-bd)+j(ad+bc-bd)$$

with the rule that $j^2 + j + 1 =0$.

I'm trying to show that $F$ is a field with these definitions, but I can't figure out a multiplicative inverse for $p\ne0$. I just need  a hint and I'll take from there. Much obliged.

Comment: Note that if $c + dj$ is the inverse of $a + bj$ then $ac-bd = 1$ and $ad +bc -bd = 0$ and try solving for a variable in one of them and substituting it into the other and simplifying.

Comment: You can also prove that it is a field without explicitly constructing the inverse. Note that $G \cong F[x] / \langle x^2 + x + 1 \rangle$ where $x^2 + x + 1$ is irreducible, hence $\langle x^2 + x + 1 \rangle$ is maximal.